# How can I correct missing lore achievements?

Tags: diablo-iii, achievements

Through various instances of downtime or pseudo-downtime (where the servers were being worked on and "you may cause some interruption in communication, ability to log in, use of in-game features, and disconnections."), I made it through quite a bit of the game without the achievements for most of Acts I and II. Things like lore for monsters, explored areas, and even bosses beaten as part of quests aren't present in my achievement log (though the quests are completed, and I'm finished with Normal).

I figured that it wouldn't be an issue, given that I was about to go through those same locations and fight those same mobs in nightmare. This works fine for quests, activity, and location achievements, but one this is *totally broken:* monster lore.

I've got the lore for a monster in my list, and can listen to it. Because of that, when I kill that monster for the first time again, I am not presented with the lore popup, and can't get it logged.

Is there any way to reset found lore? If not, is there any way to fix this on my current playthrough? If neither will work, will I get the monster lore popup on a second character in order to have it added to the bestiary achievement checklist?

Comment: Small comfort, but if nothing else, it should be fixable by the inevitable 1.1 patch -  they just need to change the achievement criteria to check the existing log.

Comment: I believe starting a new character will reset lore entries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Chris Rasys](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67336/how-can-i-correct-missing-lore-achievements#comment94411_67336) is right.

While some achievements are character specific, the criteria for the lore and bestiary achievements (and others) are not. This means you can complete each individual task with a separate character if need be, and you will still unlock the achievement in the end.

So in this case, your solution is simple: Start a new character (of a different class, or Hardcore, perhaps!) and play through Act I again. You should pick up the missing pieces and round out your achievement.